# How to insert character in middle of cell strings loop

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Sub Button1_Click()

Dim Data1 As String
Dim Data2 As String
Dim sFinal As String
Dim sLeft As String
Dim sRight As String


 'For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Data1 = Range("A1").Value
 Data2 = "-"

 sLeft = Left(Data1, 2)
sRight = Right(Data1, Len(Data1) - 2)

sFinal = sLeft & Data2 & sRight


Range("A1").Value = sFinal



 'Next i


End Sub
```

I am trying to loop trough values of column A to insert "-" after two characters in every cells... but my "For Next i" loop  has error, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is better:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

i = 1
Do Until i > Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & i).Value = Left(Trim(Range("A" & i).Value), 2) & "-" & Right(Trim(Range("A" & i).Value), Len(Trim(Range("A" & i).Value)) - 2)
i = i + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, that's more clever that my insert code, there is only a small error, code above from value e.g. 234567 makes 23-234567 instead of 23-4567

Comment: @FotoDJ My bad.. I've fixed that now - take the (edited) code above

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.